# Invalidating a facebook access token?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Is it possible to invalidate a facebook access token?

I need to do this due to the recent deprecation of offline_access.

The problem is that the token cannot be extended beyond 60 days. Even if the user returns to the app (unless I am misunderstanding?)

So, what I want to do is invalidate the token, then immediately log the user back in so that I can get a new access token back, with a new 60 day expiry date. As long as the user comes by once every two months, everything should be OK.

I do not want to log the user out of Facebook so FB.logout is not usable.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a DELETE request to `/me/permissions` which should (I think) invalidate the session for the user.

However, I don't really see why you want to do that.
You can just use the server side authentication which ends up with a 60 days token regardless of what token you had before.
So, every time you want 60 more days just authenticate the user using the server side process.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Regarding your suggestion, are you sure about that, re: "Please note, the endpoint can only be used to extend the short-lived user access_tokens. If you pass an access_token that had a long-lived expiration time, the endpoint will simply pass that same access_token back to you without altering or extending the expiration time." - so it won't update the expiration date if it's already a long expiration access token.

Comment: Yeah, in the same place it says (under *"Scenario 3: Server-side OAuth Developers"*): `If the call is made while there is still a valid long-lived user access_token for that user, the returned user access_token from this second call may be the same or may have changed, but in either case the expiration time will be set to a long expiration time`. You can't use a client token here, just a server one.

Comment: Well, I tested calling the endpoint multiple times, but the expiration time was not updated. Though perhaps this is because I did not wait a day? Have you used this in a project already?

Comment: Sorry, OK, sending DELETE to /me/permissions does work. Authorization removed. GREAT! Will not be selecting as the right answer yet though, in case there is a better way.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's gone, but after you log in again, it returns the same short-lived token. Perhaps I just have to wait a couple of hours..

Comment: Why do you insist of using client side tokens? Using server side tokens should make things easier. You don't use server side at all?

Comment: I convert the short lived token to a long lived one on the server side. As far as I know, that's the same thing (just one extra step to do the exchange). After that, the token is exactly the same as you would when you authenticate server side. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong in that using the server side auth flow you can get 60 more days when ever you make the user go through the process.

Comment: Well, I just exchanged my 60 day token again, and it just returns the same token, with the same expiry. This 24 hours after first getting the longer token. This isn't working.

Comment: I keep telling you that it won't work with client token and extending it, use the server side auth. I don't understand why you keep holding your position and not willing to try it.

Comment: As far as I know, extending a client token will return the same kind of token you will get if you use server side auth. Have you tested this yourself ?

Comment: Ok, I tested it and I don't get new expiration time. The documentation says something else but in practice nothing changes. However, if I issue a DELETE request to `me/permissions` and then try the server side flow I get a new token with new expiration time.

Comment: Sending a DELETE to /me/permissions doesn't work as of 2014-10-24. It results in a HTTP 400 Bad Request, saying "Unsupported delete request."

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously consider avoiding the Facebook Javascript SDK like the plague as it is asynchronous which in reality means Facebook is secure but your website is not.

I've just begun to rebuild my login flow and I am wondering if this part of my code may come in handy for managing user tokens:

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $fb_error = $e->getResult();
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}


//https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/
switch ($fb_error['error']['error_subcode']) {
    case '458':
    //Returned on app trying something or user attempting an action after app deauth
    //Can do database cleannup operations from this
        $fb_error = '458 - User removed the app from user settings';
        break;
    case '460':
    //App is no longer reauthorized and the user is trying something ?
    //Stop user from all activities if this comes up as they may deauth then try perform an action
        $fb_error = '460 - User needs to reauthorize';
        break;
    case '463':
    //Expired Token
    //This is where we autolog the user back in
        $fb_error = '463 - Token has expired and a new one needs to be requested';
        //need to somehow get the login request code from another page to hide it
        //or use htaccess tricks
        $facebook->getAccessToken();
        break;
    case '467':
    //Invalid Token
    //This is where we autolog the user back in
        $fb_error = '467 - Token is invalid and a new one needs to be requested';
        break;
}
```

You could output the errors to the page for testing:

```
echo 'Error Subcode: '.$fb_error.'<br/>';
echo 'Facebook Error Dump:<br/>';
var_dump($e);
```

Note that PHP switch works like a single `if` statement with multiple answers (case).

I would recommend for code speed optimization reordering the switch to have the most common errors listed at the top of the switch as the way PHP switch works is to run down the list until it finds a case match to the error code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/), you don't need to do anything complicated.

In the user login process, retrieve a short-lived access token and exchange it for a long-lived access token, which is valid for 60 days.

If a user logs out and logs in several times during the day, he will receive the same access token (probably) but expiration time won't update. But after at least one day pass you will receive a new long lived access token with new expiration time.

The only possible issue is scenario in which user is constantly logged in for more than two months (more than 60 days). For such scenarios (even that is barely possible) I code a little timeout function which will, when token expires, renew it in the background.

I refactor my code to retrieve and use long lived tokens yesterday afternoon, so it isn't passed enough time to tell for sure, but according to the mentioned Facebook documentation, it should be like that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to invalidate the access token.

It will return you a new extended 60-day token if you use a **new** short-lived access token to exchange for it. That specific short-lived token is always given to you when the user uses the app again. Use the client-side auth flow (JS SDK) so you're sure you get the short-lived-token. Use the new endpoint for exachanging tokens.

For more info check the [facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: But if I use the short lived token, and then exchange via the endpoint, that same old long lived token (which may only have a few days left before expiry), is returned. (note, i haven't yet waited a day before trying again)

Comment: @dragonjet - can you please explain what does "short-lived token is always given to you when the user uses the app again" mean? Who is it given to me, how can i get it? Thanks!