# Facebook access token expire security

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

I want to incorporate Faccbook login into my app, but I am first trying to understand the concept of Facebook's security regarding access token expiration.

1)As far as I understand the purpose of access tokens is to provide "statelessness." Facebook states the access token is valid for an hour or two. What if someone steals the access token very early, will they be able to use this access token to make calls as the victim for a few hours then?

2) An extension of the first question, Facebook also offers long-lived access tokens which are valid for 2 months. If this token was stolen would the attacker be able to pose as the victim for 2 months then?

3) What if an access token was stolen, if it is stateless, how would you invalidate/terminate that access token (technically how is this done)?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, if someone steals the Token, he will be able to make calls with it. But you can secure them with [appsecret_proof](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof) - and you don´t need to worry about Access Tokens at all while using one of the official SDKs in most cases.

2) Yes.

3) Ther are other threads about that question with an answer, for example: [Invalidating a facebook access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704114/invalidating-a-facebook-access-token)